# Android Running the same broadcast at two different times of the day

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to run my service at two different times of the day for example every day at 9.40am and 3.30pm. I tried with the following code which i constructed yet it only runs the last alarm i sets and not both the alarms. Please help me with the code. thank you in advance. I have tried with the similar questions but it still didn't give me a good result.

```
**// set the alarm manager**
        this.context = this;

        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 47);

        Calendar updateTime2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
        updateTime2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 49);

        Intent alarm = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        Intent alarm2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarm,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarm2,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC, updateTime2.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this because the second one overrides the first one. You can solve this by setting set an identifier for each intent for example.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the same Intent, the later will overwrites the former. You can add an action for each intent to separate them, like below

```
Intent alarm = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarm.setAction("my.app.package.ACTION_ALARM_9_40AM");

Intent alarm2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarm2.setAction("my.app.package.ACTION_ALARM_3_30PM");
```

I hope this may help you.

Comment: Hi, can u explain how to run this only once a day? because after setting the alarms, it runs when ever i open the activity no matter the alarm time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by my self. I used different ID's and it worked perfectly.

```
// set the alarm manager
        this.context = this;

        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 16);

        Calendar updateTime2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        updateTime2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 25);

        Intent alarm = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarm,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);


        Intent alarm2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 1, alarm2,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC, updateTime2.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);

        lvCustomList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_custom_list);
        showList();
```